# Commons: can each non-admin user create groups?

Tags: 7

I wan to configure a Drupal Common site so that every user can create groups. Can I do so? how? Thanks.

And is there any documentation anywhere for commons? OR a support forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Straight out of the box, each Commons user can create groups.